# How to minimize this function of two variables

Tags: polynomials, optimization, numerical-optimization

I'm trying to minimize this function of $s$ over some bounds of $x$ and $y$.
The function is
$$\frac{s x y + 1}{a b s^{3} x y + a s^{2} \left(b + x\right) + s x y + 1}$$
$a$ and $b$ are constants, and I am chiefly concerned about the minimization over some range of $s$, which happens to be a few orders of magnitude.
How would I classify this type of optimization? Is there any python scipy capability to solve it? [scipy.optimize.minimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize) can't seem to handle the range of s.
For context, this is the Laplace Transform representation of an electrical circuit.

Comment: You are in the context of the optimization of a [(generalized) Rayleigh quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient). See as well [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/qam/1974-32-02/S0033-569X-1974-0430427-9/S0033-569X-1974-0430427-9.pdf). The extremas can be interpreted as eigenvalues of a certain matrix.

Comment: Two things : 1) you consider in your first sentence a limited range for $x,y$ and further on, a limited range for $s$. Which ones are the most important ? 2) A little remark: a simplification occurs if you look for the maximization of the inverse of your function.

Comment: SInce x and y are actually the values of a resistor and capacitor, respectively, then for practical reasons, 0<x<3, and 1e-9 < y < 30e-6. The function is actually evaluated after substituting for s=jw, where j = sqrt(-1), and w is the radian frequency, and for my circuit, I'm concerned with 1e2 < w/(2pi) < 1e6. I don't understand those links. I guess I am only prepared to plug my problem into scipy and get an answer.